# Knockout components communication

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application, knockout-components

I have a web app that I want to convert to and SPA using ko components. I wonder how to do a kind of inter component communication.

For example I want a "notification" component in which every single component can send notifications.

I managed to find a solution by sharing an observable array in the main view model:

```
var VM = function() {
    var self = this;

    this._notifications = ko.observableArray([]);
   this.notifications = {
        addInfo: function(text){
            self._notifications.push(text);
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
<comp1 params="{app: $data}"></comp1><br/>
<comp2 params="{app: $data}"></comp2><br/>
<notif params="{app: $data}"></notif>
```

See here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/nveron/j4829y7p/

I'm not completely satisfied with this solution, I would rather have kept the notification data in the notify component.

Do you have any idea to deal with that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `ko.subscribable` to implement a simple pub/sub message bus:

- `ko.subscribable.subscribe` to subscribe to new messages
- `ko.subscribable.notifySubscribers` to publish new messages

  *More about this in [this article](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html) by Ryan Niemeyer.*

In your case, you can create a global `postbox` object based on `ko.subscribable`. Componenents publish messages in it and notification vm subscribes to it.

You can even publish and subscribe to message by topic.

[**`Demo: JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4829y7p/2/)

### postbox:

```
var postbox = (function() {
    var pb = new ko.subscribable();
    return {    
        subscribe: function(handler, topic) {
            pb.subscribe(handler, null, topic)
        },        
        publish: function(message, topic) {
            pb.notifySubscribers(message, topic);
        }
    };
}());
```

### a component:

```
var comp1 = function(params) {           
    this.addToNotif = function(){
        postbox.publish("comp1 was here");
    }
}
```

### notif:

```
...
postbox.subscribe(function(message) {
    self.notifs.push(message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at the knockout-postbox by rniemeyer I think that will be the solution.